# CMake file(INSTALL files DESTINATION dir) with symbolic links

Tags: cmake

I am using FILE(INSTALL files) but some of the files are symbolic links. Can I tell CMake to dereference the symbolic link instead of creating a symbolic link on destination?

Comment: Please, if you think the answer is correct mark is as answer, it worked for me and I guess I would find it faster if it would be marked as correct answer

Answer (score 21):

You can dereference the files programmatically before passing them to `install(FILES ...)`:

```
set (_resolvedFiles "")
foreach (_file ${_files})
    get_filename_component(_resolvedFile "${_file}" REALPATH)
    list (APPEND _resolvedFiles "${_resolvedFile}")
endforeach()
install(FILES ${_resolvedFiles} DESTINATION ${_dest})
```

Comment: This is the right answer among many others that say this is not possible. Thx

Comment: This is only possible if the files already exist at configure time. It does not work for installing files symlinked by an ExternalProject dependency (because they are not built at configure time).